# kdb passing column names into functions

Tags: kdb

I have a table

```
t: flip `ref`a`b`c`d`e!(til 10;10?10;10?10;10?10;10?10;10?10)

ref a   b   c   d   e
0   5   3   3   9   1
1   1   9   0   0   0
2   5   9   4   1   7
3   0   0   5   1   3
4   2   6   8   9   3
5   3   2   0   6   6
6   7   6   4   9   8
7   4   8   9   7   2
8   7   0   8   8   3
9   7   9   0   4   8
```

how can I set all values in columns a,b,c ,.. to 0Ni if their value equals the value in column ref without having to do a single line update for every columns?

So something taht would look a bit like (which returns ERROR:type)

```
{update x:?[x=t;0Ni;x] from t} each `a`b`c`....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer involves working with strings, this can often get very messy. To avoid this it is possible to build up the query by passing column names as symbols instead. The dictionary for the functional select can be built up using the following function:

```
q){y!enlist[({?[y=x;0Ni;y]};x)],/:y:(),y}[`ref;`a`b`c]
a| ({?[y=x;0Ni;x]};`ref) `a
b| ({?[y=x;0Ni;x]};`ref) `b
c| ({?[y=x;0Ni;x]};`ref) `c
```

The initial column is `x` and it allows to any number of columns to be passed as `y` for comparison.

This can then be added into the functional select:

```
q)![t;();0b;{y!enlist[({?[y=x;0Ni;y]};x)],/:y:(),y}[`ref;`a`b`c]]
ref a b c d e
-------------
0   4 5 8 4 8
1   2 6   9 1
2   8 4 7 2 9
3   0 1 2 7 5
4   5 3   0 4
5   8 3   1 6
6   5 7 4 9 6
7   2 8 2 2 1
8     2 7 1 8
9   6 1 8 8 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You may reuse the next code snippet

```
t: flip `ref`a`b`c`d`e!(til 10;10?10;10?10;10?10;10?10;10?10);
columns: `a`b`c`d`e;
![t;();0b;columns!{parse "?[",x,"=ref;0Ni;",x,"]" }each string columns]
```

Where updated columns are put in `columns` list.
And functional update, which maps every column `X` to value `?[x=ref;0Ni;x]`, is used

Comment: Thanks Anton. One question... what does the ![t;();0b; do? I can see that I get some dict which contains some function(?). but I have no clue what the first part does

Comment: Hi @chrise. This construction is called [Functional update](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/functional-queries-dynamic-sql#functional-update). Actually, not much difference from usual `update` statement, but much more flexible. As it allows to use dictionary of column names/values to define columns to update